# Four-wire photoelectric sensor load wiring

Tags: proximity-sensor

I’m a woodworker and a DIY’er and I have been trying to hook up a Banner QS18VPSD sensor 4 wire with a strobe light to my central dust collection. I found a [YouTube video](https://youtu.be/85BA5C0qnKo?si=31D1rxSfrqr-2hkx) that explains it all.

I can never get the strobe light to come on. At first I thought maybe it was the sensor so I bought another; same problem. I followed the directions that came with the sensor; same problem.

The closest I got was getting the strobe light to come on all the time. And when I blocked the sensor then it would go out.

I been working on this for 2 weeks. I get power to the sensor with the little green power light, and the red beam light. The strobe light works when it has power directly hooked up to it. It just seems when I go through the sensor it won’t come on. Here is a picture of my wiring

[image]

What could I be doing wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Attach the datasheets for the photocell, light, and power supply. Link screenshots of the relevant sections of the video.

Comment: Is the sensor P/N actually QS18VPSD as you've written?  Or is it a QS18VP6D ?

Comment: Please draw a wiring diagram or schematic, there is a tool if you edit

Answer (score 1):

[image]

*Figure 1. The wiring diagram makes it clear. [Datasheet](https://www.turck.de/datasheet/_en/edb_3061654_gbr_en.pdf).*

- Brown: supply + (looks OK)
- Blue: supply - (looks OK)

You can have the strobe "normally on" by connecting its red + to the switch's white and the strobe's black - to blue.

You can have the strobe "normally off" by connecting its red + to the switch's black and the strobe's black - to blue.

Leave the unused output disconnected.

The sensor is rated for 100 mA output. You should check that your strobe does not exceed this current.

Comment: So basically he needs to rewire the black the comes from the flasher to the blue wire (disconnecting the black wire) , and possibly swap the red from the flasher to connect to the black from the sensor if the flasher  is on when it should be off

Comment: Actually there seems to be two very similar videos on this. The clearer video shows the wiring as: Sensor BROWN to +POWER, Sensor BLACK to Light RED, Sensor BLUE to -POWER, Light BLACK to -POWER, Sensor WHITE not used. The better video is here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?app=desktop&v=JIUpPrCKCU8

Comment: As you said, and it still doesn’t work

Comment: Then update your question with a photo of the new wiring and tell us what voltage your power supply is. Also you should respond to Nedd's question in the comments.